# How to remove body spaces

Tags: html

I use this CSS codes for generating fixed menu bar and I am facing margin problem, I use top and left margin 0 but this problem happened. Please check following link for detail.

[Please check this URL](http://www.imagesup.net/dm-813744791913.png)

```
 #menu ul{
   margin-top:0px;
   margin-left:0;
   background:#999999;
   height:50px;
   width:100%;
   position:fixed;
   border:solid green;
   list-style:none;
   padding:0;
}
ul {
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
a {
   display:block;
   width:60px;
}
li {
   display:inline;
}
li {
   float:left;
}
a {
  display:block;
  width:60px;
}
```

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to reset the margin and padding

```
* {
   padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a default style sheet that "reset" the style.

Like this : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: You don't need to reset *everything* just to change the margin around the `body`. This is overkill.

Comment: but it's cross browser, each browser has a different "base" style

Answer (score 2):

This is because of body margin, You can remove it simply:

```
body{
    margin:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a valuable solution and may cause some errors in some components in that page such as color-picker, date-picker or anything else